# What kind of Brazilian Arthropoda is this?

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

It looks like a Diplopoda, but I've never seen anything like that. A friend took those pictures in the Brazilian Cerrado (Goiás state, Brazil) these days (October, start of rainfall in Spring). It was inside a country house, she already found it dead.

She said it has about 3 cm (~1.2") long. We can see it's not so small as a Symphyla or Pauropoda. Looks like it has 12 pairs of legs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Similar to *Allothereua maculate* and *Scutigera coleoptrata*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was fooled by the red marks in its back, that made me believe they were each pair of marks in a segment. Looks like they're distributed in one pair of red marks for each 2 segments. Maybe that's a mimic of some similar Diplopoda (which usually have such colored marks, see for instance *Rudiloria*)?

Looks like it's some species of [Scutigera](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Scutigera&tbm=isch) or some related group.